# err-to-many-redirects при перенаправлении с http на https

Tags: nginx

Добрый вечер. Настроил ssl так, чтобы все запросы перенаправлялись с http на https, но теперь возникает ошибка ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.key;

    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

    if ($http_host ~ "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}") {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        index   index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.(html|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|pdf|txt|tar|ico)$ {
        root /var/www/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ /.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так, код я не проверил, но в теории работать должен.

```
server {
 listen 80;

 server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;

 location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 permanent;
 }

}

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;

 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.key;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
  index   index.html index.php;
 }

 if ($http_host ~ "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}") {
  return 444;
 }

 location ~* \.(html|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|pdf|txt|tar|ico)$ {
     root /var/www/;
     expires 30d;
 }

 location ~ /.ht {
     deny all;
 }
}
```

Comment: Загружает сайт в обычном режиме, не перенаправляя на https.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, перепутал местами порты, попробуйте сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Перенаправление запросов лучше всего делать с помощью кодов возврата. В http для этого предусмотрен код 301 (постоянный редирект). 
В nginx для этих целей используется директива **return код_состояния url**:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    return 301 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
  }
}
```

При переходе на https важно включить компрессию:

```
htttp {
  gzip on;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss     text/javascript;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
}
```

---

Вам также может помочь статья [Nginx.  Переход с http  на https](https://www.influunt.ru/nginx-switch-from-http-to-https)